# Why will my cluster not render properly in Google Maps for Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps, angular-changedetection

We are having issues with clustering on our Google Map for Angular. This is Angular's own Google Map (@angular/google-map --> https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/google-maps-as-an-angular-component), not the Angular wrapper for regular Google Maps that most people use (@angular/agm --> https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/).

Here's a video capture of what the issue is:

https://watch.screencastify.com/v/vWmHRyKOB1dTStNxBCvw

You'll notice that the map starts out showing a cluster of 17 pins near Calgary, Alberta, Canada. Then I switch to a different company which has a different set of pins. I click on a few clusters zooming in each time. Then I switch back to the original company. The cluster now shows 2 pins. Zooming in/out one level fixes this. Sometimes the issue is that NO cluster shows up for the original company after switching back to it, and again zooming in/out fixes it. The issues seems to happen only after zooming into a cluster a few levels then switching the company.

The map is nested inside a wrapper component we created (map-wrapper.component.html):

```
<google-map
    #map
    height="100%"
    width="100%"
    [options]="mapOptions"
    [zoom]="zoom"
    [center]="center"
    (zoomChanged)="zoomChange()">
    <!-- OK site markers -->
    <map-marker-clusterer imagePath="assets/img/clusters/cluster_green">
        <map-marker
            *ngFor="let site of okSites"
            [position]="site.position"
            [title]="site.displayName"
            [icon]="site.pinIcon" 
            #marker="mapMarker"
            fit="true"
            [options]="okPinOptions"
            (mapClick)="markerClicked(marker, site)"
            (mapMouseover)="enableMouseover ? markerClicked(marker, site) : null">
        </map-marker>
    </map-marker-clusterer>
    <!-- Not OK sites (always unclustered) -->
    <map-marker
        *ngFor="let site of notOkSites"
        [position]="site.position"
        [title]="site.displayName"
        [icon]="site.pinIcon"
        #marker="mapMarker"
        fit="true"
        [options]="notOkPinOptions"
        (mapClick)="markerClicked(marker, site)"
        (mapMouseover)="enableMouseover ? markerClicked(marker, site) : null">
    </map-marker>
</google-map>
```

map-wrapper.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mtx-map-wrapper',
  templateUrl: './map-wrapper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map-wrapper.component.scss', '../../../../styles/colors.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MapWrapperComponent implements OnInit {
...

  @ViewChild('map') map: GoogleMap;

  @Input() okSites: MapPinData[] = [];
  @Input() notOkSites: MapPinData[] = [];

...

  constructor(
    private _siteStatusClient: CorViewApi.SiteStatusClient,
    private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private _notificationService: NotificationService,
    private _router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
...
  }

  public zoomChange(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Since we have change detection set to OnPush, we need to manually trigger change detection:
      this._cdr.detectChanges();
    });
  }

  public fitBounds(bounds: google.maps.LatLngBoundsLiteral): void {
    this.map.fitBounds(bounds);
    // Since we have change detection set to OnPush, we need to manually trigger change detection:
    this.detectChanges();
  }

  public detectChanges(): void {
    this._cdr.detectChanges();
  }

  public markForCheck(): void {
    this._cdr.markForCheck();
  }

  public detach(): void {
    this._cdr.detach();
  }

  public reattach(): void {
    this._cdr.reattach();
  }
}
```

We also have a parent component that loads the data for the pins. It fires a `_siteDataReady` event that we subscribe to and in the subscription we bind the arrays of pins (`okSitesBound` and `notOkSitesBound`):

```
 private subscribeToSiteDataReady(): Subscription {
    return this._siteDataReady.subscribe((ready: boolean) => {
      if (ready) {
        this.okSitesBound = this._okSitesUnbound;
        this.notOkSitesBound = this._notOkSitesUnbound;

        if (!this.disableAutoZoom) {
          this.mapWrapper.fitBounds({
            east: this._eastMostLng,
            west: this._westMostLng,
            north: this._northMostLat,
            south: this._southMostLat
          });
        }

        // The MapWrapper's change detection strategy is set to OnPush,
        // therefore need to detect changes manually:
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.mapWrapper.detectChanges();
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

You'll note that our change detection strategy for the map-wrapper is OnPush so we have to call detectChanges manually whenever there is a change. This is because keeping the default change strategy REALLY slows the map down when rendering the pins, especially for large data sets like Transcanada Pipelines - Canada. I've tested what happens when we keep the default change strategy and the cluster on the first company renders properly with the correct number, but we have to wait an extremely long time when the number of pins is large.

So I'm wondering if I'm handling change detection properly when the strategy is OnPush. Am I calling detectChanges() the right way, in the right places? I've also tried markForCheck(). I've tried setting a 10 second delay in the timeout before it calls detectChanges() just to see if calling detectChanges() has any effect when I KNOW the rendering is done and the call stack is finishes (which strangely didn't work). I've tried looking for an event that fires from the map when the pins are done rendering but can't find anything (there's `tilesloaded` but that fires before the pins are rendered). I've also tried detach() and reattach() with the default change detection strategy at the bottleneck:

```
private subscribeToSiteDataReady(): Subscription {
    return this._siteDataReady.subscribe((ready: boolean) => {
      if (ready) {
        this.mapWrapper.detach(); // <----------- HERE
        this.okSitesBound = this._okSitesUnbound;
        this.notOkSitesBound = this._notOkSitesUnbound;

        if (!this.disableAutoZoom) {
          this.mapWrapper.fitBounds({
            east: this._eastMostLng,
            west: this._westMostLng,
            north: this._northMostLat,
            south: this._southMostLat
          });
        }

        // The MapWrapper's change detection strategy is set to OnPush,
        // therefore need to detect changes manually:
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.mapWrapper.reattach(); // <----------- HERE
          this.mapWrapper.detectChanges();
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

I'm assuming the timeout will run after it finishes (attempting to) rendering the pins (am I wrong?). I'm assuming that if I detach right before the point that takes a lot of processing power and slowing the rendering of the pins down, and then reattach when it's done, it will have the same effect as using the OnPush strategy (i.e. speeds up the rendering of the pins).

There's a number of other things I've tried to no avail.

Can anyone tell me if I'm doing anything wrong? Does anyone have any recommendations?

Thanks.